# Connecting AVD emulator with local servlet

Tags: android

I've been trying to connect my android emulator with local servlet but without result. I know I should use `http://10.0.2.2:8080`, however it's still not working. The funny part is that on my real device, with my network ip, `http://192.168.1.10:8080`, servlet responds as it should. What is wrong with the emulator? I know there are tons of such topics but the only answers is always "change to 10.0.2.2"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your servlet engine (web server) does not bind/listen to 10.0.2.2?